# surveymonkey - The authorization token provided was invalid

Tags: node.js, surveymonkey

I'm trying to fetch serveymonkey response in NodeJS.
this is the response I'm getting:

```
{ 
error:
   { docs: 'https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#error-codes',
     message: 'The authorization token provided was invalid.',
     id: '1011',
     name: 'Authorization Error',
     http_status_code: 401 
    } 
}
```

And this is my code:

```
 const fetch = require('node-fetch');
  const accessToken = 'xxxxxxx';
 let options = {
   method : 'GET',
   headers: {
       Authorization: accessToken,
   },
   contentType: 'application/json'
   };

fetch('https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/surveys/6991347309/responses/6991347309',options)
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(json => console.log(json));
```

The access token I checked a lot of times I copied it right from the app.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the prefix, **bearer** in the `Authorization` header of your request:

```
Authorization: bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

For more information, see the [Authentication](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#authentication) section of the API documentation.